# Kibana: Report on different date intervals such as Today, Yesterday, Last Week

Tags: elasticsearch, data-visualization, kibana, elastic-stack

I need to display a report on Kibana that will aggregate results based on multiple date intervals. Times are mapped as float data type along with the timestamp.

Example:

```
Jobs, Yesterday, Last Week, Last Quarters
Job 1, 5hr,      10 hr,     60 hr
```

What is the best way to do this with ES and Kibana?

Comment: Have you tried anything? A guiding suggestion would be to create a chart (of whatever type) with a `Date Range` aggregation specified to your favorite bucket sizes.

Comment: I'm trying with date range aggregations, but can't find any close solution to produce the above representation.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you want it to display as:

> job N | range 1 | range 2 | range 3 | ... | range N

This may be difficult to actually get in Kibana exactly because of how it likes to split up the data table, but it's best to know *how* to get something before you even try to visualize it:

```
{
  "size" : 0,
  "aggs" : {
    "per_job": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "job",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "ranges": {
          "date_range": {
            "field": "timestamp",
            "ranges": [
              {
                "from": "now-1d/d"
              },
              {
                "from" : "now-7d/d"
              },
              {
                "from": "now-3M/M"
              }
            ]
          },
          "aggs": {
            "worked": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "hours"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What is this providing? This is grouping by each `job`, then splitting each job into three bucketed date ranges, each being longer versions of the previous range (notice there's no `"to"` specified, which you could specify as `"to" : "now"`), then finally each date range's split is summed up on the field of interest, which I assume is named hours.

How can you use this in Kibana? Well, Kibana is just a visualization tool to build these aggregations and chart or otherwise display them.

The top level aggregation is therefore going to be a `Terms` aggregation. The secondary or "sub-bucket" will be the `Date Range`, and finally the `metric` (above the `buckets`) will be the `Sum`.

Unfortunately, given that you seem to want a table view of it, there's no way that I am aware of to get the separate date ranges to just add another row *unless* you accept one table per job:

[image: Example Configuration]

Comment: Your solution works on ES, I can get the data form ES this way. But in Kibana, the representation is not what I needed.

Comment: Feel free to create an issue over at http://github.com/elastic/kibana and describe what you wanted visually to happen (mockups encouraged).